# ndepend - no dependency graph/metrics after analysis

Tags: ndepend

I can't get any form of interactive graph in VisualNDepend. There is only a black screen.

I'm using Visual NDepend v1.9.

I created a project, selected my sln and clicked on ***Run Analysis and Report***. I was presented with several graphs in html but they were low-res. Nex to the graphs were this note:

`It is recommended to use the NDepend interactive dependency Graph and interactive Dependency Matrix for an in-depth exploration of the actual architecture of your code.`

I opened VisualNDepend and checked the Dependency Graph and Dependency Matrix tabs which were empty. I went back to dashboard tab and clicked ***Run Analysis on Current Project*** but the tabs still displayed nothing. At the bottom right there is a red circle which when clicked, shows analysis complete x mins ago.

How do I display any form of graphs with ndepend? I tried on several slns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

After going through every menu item, I found that I had to explicitly click on graph->view dependency graph and matrix->view dependency matrix to actually see the stuff.